# Is there a way to get SageMath to completely simplify this family of expressions, particularly for $n = 5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sagemath

I am using SageMath for the first time. I have the following long expression, which I want to simplify for integer values of `n` from 0 to 5:

```
var('A, B, C, E, d, α, β, γ')
f = lambda n : (
   (12*A + 6*B + 4*C + 2*E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 - (11*A + 6*B + 4*C + 2*E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 - (11*A + 5*B + 4*C + 2*E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 + (10*A + 5*B + 4*C + 2*E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 - (10*A + 5*B + 3*C + 2*E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 + ( 9*A + 5*B + 3*C + 2*E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 + ( 9*A + 4*B + 3*C + 2*E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 - ( 8*A + 4*B + 3*C + 2*E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 - ( 8*A + 4*B + 3*C +   E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 + ( 7*A + 4*B + 3*C +   E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 + ( 7*A + 3*B + 3*C +   E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 3*C +   E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   E + 4*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   E + 3*α + 2*β + γ)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   E + 3*α +   β + γ)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   E + 2*α +   β + γ)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   E + 2*α +   β)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   E +   α +   β)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   E +   α)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   E)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B +   C +   E)^n
 - ( 5*A + 3*B +   C +   E)^n
 - ( 5*A + 2*B +   C +   E)^n
 + ( 4*A + 2*B +   C +   E)^n
 + ( 4*A + 2*B +   C)^n
 - ( 3*A + 2*B +   C)^n
 - ( 3*A +   B +   C)^n
 + ( 2*A +   B +   C)^n
 - ( 2*A +   B)^n
 + (   A +   B)^n
 +     A^n
)/factorial(n)
```

The command `f(0).full_simplify()` returns the correct result of `1`. The commands `f(1).full_simplify()` and `f(2).full_simplify()` return the correct result of `0`.

However, for higher integer values of `n`, the output is no longer fully simplified. The command `f(3).full_simplify()` returns the result

```
2*A^3 + 3*A^2*B + A*B^2 + 2*α^3 + α*β^2
 - 4*(A^2 + A*B)*α - (2*A^2 + 2*A*B - 3*α^2)*β - (A^2 + A*B - α^2 - α*β)*γ
```

which I was able to further simplify manually to get

```
A*(A + B)*(2*A + B - 4*α - 2*β - γ) + α*(α + β)*(2*α + β + γ)
```

Similarly, the command `f4.full_simplify()` returns the result

```
12*A^4 + 24*A^3*B + 15*A^2*B^2 + 3*A*B^3 + 2*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^3 + 4*α^4 + α*β^3 - 8*(A^2 + A*B)*α^2
 - (2*A^2 + 2*A*B - (6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α - 5*α^2)*β^2 - 1/2*(A^2 + A*B - α^2 - α*β)*γ^2 + 2*(2*A^3 + 3*A^2*B + A*B^2)*C + (2*A^3 + 3*A^2*B + A*B^2)*E - 2*(10*A^3 + 15*A^2*B + 5*A*B^2 + 4*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*E)*α
 - (10*A^3 + 15*A^2*B + 5*A*B^2 - 3*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^2 - 8*α^3 + 4*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*E + 8*(A^2 + A*B)*α)*β
 - 1/2*(10*A^3 + 15*A^2*B + 5*A*B^2 - 2*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^2 - 6*α^3 - 3*α*β^2 + 4*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*E + 8*(A^2 + A*B)*α + (4*A^2 + 4*A*B - 2*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α - 9*α^2)*β)*γ
```

which I was able to manually simplify down to

```
(A*(A + B)*(2*A + B - 4*α - 2*β - γ) + α*(α + β)*(2*α + β + γ))*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E + (4*α + 2*β + γ)/2)
```

The command `f(5).full_simplify()` returns the substantially-longer result

```
137/2*A^5 + 685/4*A^4*B + 925/6*A^3*B^2 + 60*A^2*B^3 + 103/12*A*B^4
 + 4*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^4 + 9/2*α^5 + 7/12*α*β^4 + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*C^3
 + 1/3*(76*A^2 + 76*A*B + 27*B^2 + 36*(2*A + B)*C + 12*C^2 + 6*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C)*E + 3*E^2)*α^3
 - 1/3*(4*A^2 + 4*A*B - 3*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α - 12*α^2)*β^3
 - 1/6*(A^2 + A*B - α^2 - α*β)*γ^3 + 10*(2*A^3 + 3*A^2*B + A*B^2)*C^2
 + 1/2*(6*A^3 + 9*A^2*B + 3*A*B^2 + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*C)*E^2
 - 4*(10*A^3 + 15*A^2*B + 5*A*B^2 + 4*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*E)*α^2
 - 1/6*(60*A^3 + 90*A^2*B + 30*A*B^2 - 30*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^2 - 61*α^3 + 24*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 12*(A^2 + A*B)*E - 3*(20*A^2 + 20*A*B + 9*B^2 + 12*(2*A + B)*C + 4*C^2 + 2*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C)*E + E^2)*α)*β^2
 - 1/4*(10*A^3 + 15*A^2*B + 5*A*B^2 - 2*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^2 - 6*α^3 - 3*α*β^2 + 4*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*E + 8*(A^2 + A*B)*α + (4*A^2 + 4*A*B - 2*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α - 9*α^2)*β)*γ^2
 + 16*(4*A^4 + 8*A^3*B + 5*A^2*B^2 + A*B^3)*C
 + (28*A^4 + 56*A^3*B + 35*A^2*B^2 + 7*A*B^3 + 3*(A^2 + A*B)*C^2 + 9*(2*A^3 + 3*A^2*B + A*B^2)*C)*E
 - 1/3*(55*A^4 + 110*A^3*B + 69*A^2*B^2 + 14*A*B^3 + 12*(A^2 + A*B)*C^2 + 6*(A^2 + A*B)*E^2 + 24*(2*A^3 + 3*A^2*B + A*B^2)*C + 6*(6*A^3 + 9*A^2*B + 3*A*B^2 + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*C)*E)*α
 - 1/12*(110*A^4 + 220*A^3*B + 138*A^2*B^2 + 28*A*B^3 - 96*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^3 - 135*α^4 + 24*(A^2 + A*B)*C^2 + 12*(A^2 + A*B)*E^2 - 6*(76*A^2 + 76*A*B + 27*B^2 + 36*(2*A + B)*C + 12*C^2 + 6*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C)*E + 3*E^2)*α^2 + 48*(2*A^3 + 3*A^2*B + A*B^2)*C + 12*(6*A^3 + 9*A^2*B + 3*A*B^2 + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*C)*E + 48*(10*A^3 + 15*A^2*B + 5*A*B^2 + 4*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*E)*α)*β
 - 1/12*(55*A^4 + 110*A^3*B + 69*A^2*B^2 + 14*A*B^3 - 36*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^3 - 55*α^4 - 14*α*β^3 + 12*(A^2 + A*B)*C^2 + 6*(A^2 + A*B)*E^2 - 6*(20*A^2 + 20*A*B + 9*B^2 + 12*(2*A + B)*C + 4*C^2 + 2*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C)*E + E^2)*α^2 + 3*(8*A^2 + 8*A*B - 6*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α - 23*α^2)*β^2 + 24*(2*A^3 + 3*A^2*B + A*B^2)*C + 6*(6*A^3 + 9*A^2*B + 3*A*B^2 + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*C)*E + 24*(10*A^3 + 15*A^2*B + 5*A*B^2 + 4*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 2*(A^2 + A*B)*E)*α + 2*(60*A^3 + 90*A^2*B + 30*A*B^2 - 27*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E)*α^2 - 55*α^3 + 24*(A^2 + A*B)*C + 12*(A^2 + A*B)*E - 3*(20*A^2 + 20*A*B + 9*B^2 + 12*(2*A + B)*C + 4*C^2 + 2*(6*A + 3*B + 2*C)*E + E^2)*α)*β)*γ
```

and I haven't simplified it further yet because I'm getting tired of manually slogging through these rapidly-increasingly-long expressions to completely simplify them.

**Is there any way to get SageMath to do a better job of completely simplifying these expressions?**

I did try asking Sage to factor `f(5)`, hoping it could pull out a factor of `A*(A + B)*(2*A + B - 4*α - 2*β - γ) + α*(α + β)*(2*α + β + γ)` or `6*A + 3*B + 2*C + E + (4*α + 2*β + γ)/2` since `f(4)` is equivalent to `f(3)` multiplied by the latter term and I hoped that a similar relationship might hold for `f(5)` as well, but with no luck. I also asked Sage to divide `f(5)` by those terms and simplify, but it just tacked the divisor on the end of the expression with no further simplification.

Comment: Rather than use symbolic variables, you could work in a polynomial ring: replace the first line by `R.<A, B, C, E, d, α, β, γ> = QQ[]`. Factoring might work better in this setting.

Comment: Also, since this is much more a SageMath question than a math question, it might be better to post at ask.sagemath.org.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I replaced the first line as you suggested and the `full_simplify()` and `simplify()` commands now throw error messages, but `factor()` *sort of* works - it runs without error on the non-zero `f(n)` expressions, but does not actually do any factoring of `f(3)` or `f(5)`. As for ask.sagemath.org, I asked this question there five days ago and have received no useful responses so far.

Comment: What does "fully simplified" mean? I don't mean within Sage, but for you? Is there a mathematical definition?

Comment: In the case of `f(3).factor()`, I would guess that it doesn't do any factoring because the polynomial cannot be factored. Indeed, `f(3).is_prime()` returns `True`, as does `f(5).is_prime()`. `f(3).divides(f(4))` also returns `True`.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri To me, "fully simplified" means something like "using the smallest possible number of instances of the smallest possible number of symbols (operands, operators, brackets)". The shortest possible version of the expression in question, basically.

Comment: I wonder if there is any algorithm that can accomplish that. How would you choose among $xy + xz + z$, $x(y+z) + z$, and $xy + z(x+1)$?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri That's a tricky one. Written without multiplication signs or spaces, $xy+xz+z$ is shortest overall. With multiplication signs added instead of implied, it's a tie between the first two options, and I think I prefer the second because it only has one doubled symbol ($z$) instead of two ($x$ and $z$). The tie remains when spaces are added around the operands. In all cases, the third option is the longest, and it also uses an additional symbol ($1$) not present in the first two options, so the third option is definitely out.

Comment: Maybe my example should have had the $yz$ as the last term rather than $z$, to make it more ambiguous. Now imagine a more complicated situation, like `f(5)`. There are 228 summands, so there are $2^{228}$ possible groups of terms which might have a common factor. Without an algorithm, how do you hope to find groupings that lead to particularly short answers? In other words, I don't know if this is possible without human intervention. I think this came up in the ask.sagemath.org discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146094/discussion-between-lawton-and-john-palmieri).

Answer (score 1):

I "simplified" your $f(5)$ in my answer to [your later question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4703815/409) where I sorted-through the expanded form looking for patterns and groupings. I was going to amend that answer with some notes about looking at the un-expanded form of $f(5)$, but since it's already quite long, and this question asks about it directly, I thought I'd answer separately here.

As mentioned in that other answer, the substitutions are convenient:
$$A\to a \qquad B\to b-a \qquad C\to c-(a+b) \qquad E\to d-(a+b+c)$$
$$\alpha\to e \qquad \beta\to f-e \qquad \gamma\to g-(e+f)$$
Your "$E$" in this question is "$D$" there. And your "$d$" in this question is unused, so there should be no confusion in my using "$d$" here. Finally, your "$\alpha$", "$\beta$", "$\gamma$" here are "$E$", "$F$", "$G$" there, which helps explain the $e$, $f$, $g$ in the substitutions.)

Also, as per my previous answer, I'll define
$$p := e+f+g$$
Here, I'll introduce
$$u := a+b \qquad v := c+d$$
In the context of the function $f(n)$, the terms look *slightly* more compact after the substitutions. With a bit of re-ordering to put like terms together, we have

$$\begin{align}
+ &\;a^n + (-a - c)^n + (-a - d)^n \\
+ &\;(-a + 2 c + d + p)^n + (-a + c + 2 d + p)^n + (a - 2 c - 2 d - p )^n \\
\\
+ &\;b^n + (-b - c)^n + (-b - d)^n \\
+ &\;(-b + 2 c +d + p)^n + (-b + c + 2 d + p)^n + (b - 2 c - 2 d - p)^n \\
\\
+ &\;(-a - b)^n \\
+ &\;(a + b + c)^n+(a + b + d)^n \\
+ &\;(-a - b + 2 c + 2 d + p)^n + ( a + b - c - 2 d - p)^n + ( a + b - 2 c - d - p)^n \\
\\
+ &\;c^n + d^n \\
+ &\;( -c - d)^n\\
+ &\;( c + d + e )^n + ( c + d + f )^n +( c + d + g)^n  \\
+ &\;(-c - d - f - g)^n + (-c - d - e - g)^n  +(-c - d - e - f)^n \\
+ &\;( c + d + p)^n + (-c - 2 d - p)^n + (-2 c - d - p)^n + ( 2 c + 2 d + p)^n 
\end{align}$$

In this form, we clearly see that the expression is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, in $c$ and $d$, and in $e$, $f$, $g$.

For an attempt to simplify $f(n)$ for $n$ odd, we can consider leveraging the factorization
$$x^{2m+1} + y^{2m+1} \;=\; (x+y)\;\left(x^{2m} - x^{2m-1} y + x^{2m-2} y^2 - \cdots + x y^{2m-1} + y^{2m} \right)$$
The salient point here is the factor $x+y$; conveniently pairing terms of $f(n)$ gives us some common factors, thusly:

$$\begin{align}
a^n + ( b - 2 v - p )^n \;&= \phantom{-}(u-2v-p)\;(\;\cdots\;)\\
b^n + ( a - 2 v - p )^n \;&= \phantom{-}(u-2v-p)\;(\;\cdots\;) \\
(-u)^n + (2 v + p )^n \;&=-(u-2v-p)\;(\;\cdots\;) \\
(-u + 2 v + p )^n \;&=-(u-2v-p)\;(\;\cdots\;) \\ 
\\
(- c - 2d - p)^n + (u+d)^n \;&= \phantom{-}(u - v - p )\;(\;\cdots\;)\\
(- 2c-d - p)^n + (u + c)^n \;&= \phantom{-}( u - v - p )\;(\;\cdots\;) \\
(u - 2 c - d - p)^n + c^n \;&= \phantom{-}( u - v - p )\;(\;\cdots\;) \\
(u - c - 2 d - p)^n + d^n \;&= \phantom{-}( u - v - p )\;(\;\cdots\;) \\
(- a + 2 c + d + p)^n + (-b - c)^n \;&=-(u-v-p)\;(\;\cdots\;) \\
(- b + 2 c + d + p)^n + (-a - d)^n \;&=-(u-v-p)\;(\;\cdots\;) \\
(- b + c + 2 d + p)^n + (-a - c)^n \;&=-(u-v-p)\;(\;\cdots\;) \\
(- a + c + 2 d + p)^n + (-b - d)^n \;&=-(u-v-p)\;(\;\cdots\;)
\end{align}$$

Expanding all of the "$(\;\cdots\;)$"s and combining the results is still quite an ordeal. (Maybe re-grouping everything into "multiples of $p-u$" and "multiples of $v$" would help. I haven't looked into that.) So is expanding the remaining terms to get
$$\begin{align}
&\;\phantom{+}(-v)^5 + (v+ e)^5 + (v+ f)^5 + (v+ g)^5 \\
&+(-v-f - g)^5 + (-v- e - g)^5 + (-v- e - f)^5 + (v +p)^5 \\
&= \;10 e f g(\;\cdots\;)
\end{align}$$

It's not at all obvious that the final form can be written as in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4705674/409).

Anyway, it's clear —especially after the substitutions— that there's a good bit of structure to these expressions, so there may yet be a way to get from the original form to a "reduced" form that reflects that structure.